# How to not overwrite the variable value in php?

Tags: php

We all know that a variable is vary, a old value stored to the variable is overwritten by its new value. Is there any solution that old value can't be overwrite but its remains store and the new value stored to the same variable is appended by it old value. For example; 
If

```
$var='old';
$var='new';
```

then when we echo variable the  result will come **new** but I want something like that 
 **old, new**

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: `$var='old';
$var.=', new';
echo $var;`

Comment: did you mean you want to append ?

Comment: but the values are coming from a textfield , then I store it in a variable, want to append the new submitted values by its old submitted values. Its a dynamic case, not to just store a static value in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append a value, use this:

```
$var='old';
$var .=', new';
```

For more info, read the PHP Manual's operators assignment section **[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)**.

**EDIT:**
if you get the new value from a variable, assign the variable instead like:

```
$var='old';
$newValue = 'new';
$var .=  ', '.$newValue;
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$var='old';%5Cn%20$newValue%20=%20'new';%5Cn%20$var%20.=%20',%20'.$newValue;%5Cn%20echo%20$var;%5Cn?%3E)**

**SESSION:**

If your form reloads after submitting, the value that is stored on a local variable will be lost, you can use session variable instead like:

```
if ( $_SESSION['var']) 
    $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['name'];
else 
    $_SESSION['var'] .= ', ' . $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: but the values is coming from a textfield , then I store it in a variable, want to append the new submitted values by its old submitted values

Comment: The problem is that the values are coming from a textfield , so when a user submit a form, I store its value like $var = $_POST['name'], but when user again submits a form , that value must be appended to previous submitted value..(its not a static case)

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan then you should do this `$var = ', '.$_POST['name'];` if the form reloads after submitting, that value will be lost, so you need to store it in a session instead like: `$_SESSION['var'] = ', '.$_POST['name'];`, you can then print your value like `echo $_SESSION['var'];`

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark next to it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use `.` for appending string as below:

```
$var='old';
$var .=', new';
```

Comment: but the value is coming from a textfield , then I store it in a variable, want to append the new submitted values by its old submitted values

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $_SESSION['var'] == '' ) {
    $var = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $var .= ', ' . $_POST['name'];
}
$_SESSION['var'] = $var;
```